# Configuring httpd.conf to handle both a website and subversion

Tags: apache-2.2, svn, httpd.conf

I am trying to set up an Apache2 server on Suse10. It currently serves pages for an internal website. I've installed Subversion and have the source for the internal website in version control and served with svnserve, all successfully. However, the corporate firewall doesn't allow the svnserve port (I've tested it with an unfirewalled machine, and it works). Therefore, I'm trying to get both the internal website and subversion access served by the same apache server - how do I do this?

I've tried editing httpd.conf according to http://svnbook.red-bean.com:

```
# Subversion Configuration
LoadModule dav_module           /usr/lib64/apache2/mod_dav.so
LoadModule dav_svn_module       /usr/lib64/apache2/mod_dav_svn.so

<Location /subversion>
    DAV svn
    SVNPath /var/svn/repos/
</Location>
```

but when I try to access the repository via the client

```
svn list http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

I get the error "Repository moved temporarily to 'sitename/login/login.php'; please relocate." Obviously, the webserver is redirecting me towards the internal website, and not recognizing I'm trying to access the subversion repository.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The key is to access the repository like this:

```
svn list http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/subversion
```

Then it works as expected.